# Should I be worried that yum update suddenly wants to update well over 100 packages on my CentOS 6 system?

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

I get an email alert whenever there's something to update, and typically do them that day.  This tends to happen most days.

For whatever reason I've had no alerts since 20th July until today (I believe I did a manual yum update the other day just to check, and sure enough there was nothing to do).

Today's update lists a LOT of things.  Is this just a backlog from 20th July onwards?  Why wasn't yum updating anything in that time?

Has there been some major security flaw that has caused everyone to update their software?  Or has something gone wrong in my system?  Or have the repos been compromised?

Thanks

```
ImageMagick.x86_64                    6.7.2.7-2.el6                      base
ImageMagick-devel.x86_64              6.7.2.7-2.el6                      base
abrt.x86_64                           2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
abrt-addon-ccpp.x86_64                2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
abrt-addon-kerneloops.x86_64          2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
abrt-addon-python.x86_64              2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
abrt-cli.x86_64                       2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
abrt-libs.x86_64                      2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
abrt-tui.x86_64                       2.0.8-34.el6.centos                base
at.x86_64                             3.1.10-48.el6                      base
augeas-libs.x86_64                    1.0.0-10.el6                       base
authconfig.x86_64                     6.1.12-23.el6                      base
b43-openfwwf.noarch                   5.2-10.el6                         base
bash.x86_64                           4.1.2-33.el6                       base
bind-libs.x86_64                      32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.2          updates
bind-utils.x86_64                     32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.2          updates
binutils.x86_64                       2.20.51.0.2-5.43.el6               base
biosdevname.x86_64                    0.6.2-1.el6                        base
centos-release.x86_64                 6-7.el6.centos.12.3                base
chkconfig.x86_64                      1.3.49.3-5.el6                     base
cpp.x86_64                            4.4.7-16.el6                       base
cpuspeed.x86_64                       1:1.5-22.el6                       base
cronie.x86_64                         1.4.4-15.el6                       base
cronie-anacron.x86_64                 1.4.4-15.el6                       base
cups-libs.x86_64                      1:1.4.2-72.el6                     base
curl.x86_64                           7.19.7-46.el6                      base
dejavu-fonts-common.noarch            2.33-1.el6                         base
dejavu-lgc-sans-mono-fonts.noarch     2.33-1.el6                         base
dejavu-sans-mono-fonts.noarch         2.33-1.el6                         base
device-mapper.x86_64                  1.02.95-3.el6_7.1                  updates
device-mapper-event.x86_64            1.02.95-3.el6_7.1                  updates
device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64       1.02.95-3.el6_7.1                  updates
device-mapper-libs.x86_64             1.02.95-3.el6_7.1                  updates
device-mapper-multipath.x86_64        0.4.9-87.el6                       base
device-mapper-multipath-libs.x86_64   0.4.9-87.el6                       base
dhclient.x86_64                       12:4.1.1-49.P1.el6.centos          base
dhcp-common.x86_64                    12:4.1.1-49.P1.el6.centos          base
dmidecode.x86_64                      1:2.12-6.el6                       base
dracut.noarch                         004-388.el6                        base
dracut-kernel.noarch                  004-388.el6                        base
e2fsprogs.x86_64                      1.41.12-22.el6                     base
e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64                 1.41.12-22.el6                     base
efibootmgr.x86_64                     0.5.4-13.el6                       base
elfutils.x86_64                       0.161-3.el6                        base
elfutils-libelf.x86_64                0.161-3.el6                        base
elfutils-libs.x86_64                  0.161-3.el6                        base
ethtool.x86_64                        2:3.5-6.el6                        base
fprintd.x86_64                        0.1-22.git04fd09cfa.el6            base
fprintd-pam.x86_64                    0.1-22.git04fd09cfa.el6            base
gcc.x86_64                            4.4.7-16.el6                       base
gdbm.x86_64                           1.8.0-38.el6                       base
ghostscript.x86_64                    8.70-21.el6                        base
ghostscript-devel.x86_64              8.70-21.el6                        base
glibc.x86_64                          2.12-1.166.el6_7.1                 updates
glibc-common.x86_64                   2.12-1.166.el6_7.1                 updates
glibc-devel.x86_64                    2.12-1.166.el6_7.1                 updates
glibc-headers.x86_64                  2.12-1.166.el6_7.1                 updates
glusterfs.x86_64                      3.6.0.54-1.el6                     base
glusterfs-api.x86_64                  3.6.0.54-1.el6                     base
glusterfs-libs.x86_64                 3.6.0.54-1.el6                     base
gnutls.x86_64                         2.8.5-18.el6                       base
gnutls-utils.x86_64                   2.8.5-18.el6                       base
gpxe-roms-qemu.noarch                 0.9.7-6.14.el6                     base
grep.x86_64                           2.20-3.el6                         base
grub.x86_64                           1:0.97-94.el6                      base
hal-info.noarch                       20090716-5.el6                     base
httpd.x86_64                          2.2.15-45.el6.centos               base
httpd-tools.x86_64                    2.2.15-45.el6.centos               base
hwdata.noarch                         0.233-14.1.el6                     base
initscripts.x86_64                    9.03.49-1.el6.centos               base
iproute.x86_64                        2.6.32-45.el6                      base
iptables.x86_64                       1.4.7-16.el6                       base
iptables-ipv6.x86_64                  1.4.7-16.el6                       base
iputils.x86_64                        20071127-20.el6                    base
irqbalance.x86_64                     2:1.0.7-5.el6                      base
iscsi-initiator-utils.x86_64          6.2.0.873-14.el6                   base
kernel.x86_64                         2.6.32-573.1.1.el6                 updates
kernel-firmware.noarch                2.6.32-573.1.1.el6                 updates
kernel-headers.x86_64                 2.6.32-573.1.1.el6                 updates
kexec-tools.x86_64                    2.0.0-286.el6                      base
kpartx.x86_64                         0.4.9-87.el6                       base
krb5-libs.x86_64                      1.10.3-42.el6                      base
libX11.x86_64                         1.6.0-6.el6                        base
libX11-common.noarch                  1.6.0-6.el6                        base
libX11-devel.x86_64                   1.6.0-6.el6                        base
libcgroup.x86_64                      0.40.rc1-16.el6                    base
libcom_err.x86_64                     1.41.12-22.el6                     base
libcurl.x86_64                        7.19.7-46.el6                      base
libdrm.x86_64                         2.4.59-2.el6                       base
libgcc.x86_64                         4.4.7-16.el6                       base
libgomp.x86_64                        4.4.7-16.el6                       base
libgudev1.x86_64                      147-2.63.el6                       base
libpcap.x86_64                        14:1.4.0-4.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6  base
libreport.x86_64                      2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-cli.x86_64                  2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-compat.x86_64               2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-plugin-kerneloops.x86_64    2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-plugin-logger.x86_64        2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-plugin-mailx.x86_64         2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-plugin-reportuploader.x86_64
                                      2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-plugin-rhtsupport.x86_64    2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libreport-python.x86_64               2.0.9-24.el6.centos                base
libsemanage.x86_64                    2.0.43-5.1.el6                     base
libss.x86_64                          1.41.12-22.el6                     base
libstdc++.x86_64                      4.4.7-16.el6                       base
libudev.x86_64                        147-2.63.el6                       base
libuser.x86_64                        0.56.13-8.el6_7                    updates
libvirt.x86_64                        0.10.2-54.el6                      base
libvirt-client.x86_64                 0.10.2-54.el6                      base
libvirt-python.x86_64                 0.10.2-54.el6                      base
libxcb.x86_64                         1.9.1-3.el6                        base
libxcb-devel.x86_64                   1.9.1-3.el6                        base
libxml2.x86_64                        2.7.6-20.el6                       base
libxml2-python.x86_64                 2.7.6-20.el6                       base
logrotate.x86_64                      3.7.8-23.el6                       base
lsof.x86_64                           4.82-5.el6                         base
lvm2.x86_64                           2.02.118-3.el6_7.1                 updates
lvm2-libs.x86_64                      2.02.118-3.el6_7.1                 updates
man-pages-overrides.noarch            6.7.5-1.el6                        base
mdadm.x86_64                          3.3.2-5.el6                        base
microcode_ctl.x86_64                  1:1.17-20.el6                      base
mlocate.x86_64                        0.22.2-6.el6                       base
module-init-tools.x86_64              3.9-25.el6                         base
nc.x86_64                             1.84-24.el6                        base
ncurses.x86_64                        5.7-4.20090207.el6                 base
ncurses-base.x86_64                   5.7-4.20090207.el6                 base
ncurses-libs.x86_64                   5.7-4.20090207.el6                 base
netcf-libs.x86_64                     0.2.4-3.el6                        base
nfs-utils.x86_64                      1:1.2.3-64.el6                     base
nfs-utils-lib.x86_64                  1.1.5-11.el6                       base
ntp.x86_64                            4.2.6p5-5.el6.centos               base
ntpdate.x86_64                        4.2.6p5-5.el6.centos               base
ntsysv.x86_64                         1.3.49.3-5.el6                     base
numad.x86_64                          0.5-12.20150602git.el6             base
openldap.x86_64                       2.4.40-5.el6                       base
openssh.x86_64                        5.3p1-111.el6                      base
openssh-clients.x86_64                5.3p1-111.el6                      base
openssh-server.x86_64                 5.3p1-111.el6                      base
openssl.x86_64                        1.0.1e-42.el6                      base
pam_passwdqc.x86_64                   1.0.5-8.el6                        base
parted.x86_64                         2.1-29.el6                         base
pcre.x86_64                           7.8-7.el6                          base
pcre-devel.x86_64                     7.8-7.el6                          base
perl.x86_64                           4:5.10.1-141.el6                   base
perl-CGI.x86_64                       3.51-141.el6                       base
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64         1:2.021-141.el6                    base
perl-Compress-Zlib.x86_64             2.021-141.el6                      base
perl-IO-Compress-Base.x86_64          2.021-141.el6                      base
perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.x86_64          2.021-141.el6                      base
perl-Module-Pluggable.x86_64          1:3.90-141.el6                     base
perl-Pod-Escapes.x86_64               1:1.04-141.el6                     base
perl-Pod-Simple.x86_64                1:3.13-141.el6                     base
perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64                4:1.9721-141.el6                   base
perl-libs.x86_64                      4:5.10.1-141.el6                   base
perl-version.x86_64                   3:0.77-141.el6                     base
pinentry.x86_64                       0.7.6-8.el6                        base
policycoreutils.x86_64                2.0.83-24.el6                      base
polkit.x86_64                         0.96-11.el6                        base
procps.x86_64                         3.2.8-33.el6                       base
pulseaudio-libs.x86_64                0.9.21-21.el6                      base
pulseaudio-libs-glib2.x86_64          0.9.21-21.el6                      base
python.x86_64                         2.6.6-64.el6                       base
python-devel.x86_64                   2.6.6-64.el6                       base
python-libs.x86_64                    2.6.6-64.el6                       base
python-virtinst.noarch                0.600.0-29.el6                     base
qemu-img.x86_64                       2:0.12.1.2-2.479.el6               base
qemu-kvm.x86_64                       2:0.12.1.2-2.479.el6               base
quota.x86_64                          1:3.17-23.el6                      base
rng-tools.x86_64                      5-1.el6                            base
rpm.x86_64                            4.8.0-47.el6                       base
rpm-libs.x86_64                       4.8.0-47.el6                       base
rpm-python.x86_64                     4.8.0-47.el6                       base
seabios.x86_64                        0.6.1.2-30.el6                     base
selinux-policy.noarch                 3.7.19-279.el6                     base
selinux-policy-targeted.noarch        3.7.19-279.el6                     base
sg3_utils-libs.x86_64                 1.28-8.el6                         base
sos.noarch                            3.2-28.el6.centos                  base
spice-glib.x86_64                     0.26-4.el6                         base
spice-gtk.x86_64                      0.26-4.el6                         base
spice-gtk-python.x86_64               0.26-4.el6                         base
spice-server.x86_64                   0.12.4-12.el6                      base
strace.x86_64                         4.8-10.el6                         base
sudo.x86_64                           1.8.6p3-19.el6                     base
systemtap-runtime.x86_64              2.7-2.el6                          base
sysvinit-tools.x86_64                 2.87-6.dsf.el6                     base
tar.x86_64                            2:1.23-13.el6                      base
tcpdump.x86_64                        14:4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6 base
time.x86_64                           1.7-38.el6                         base
udev.x86_64                           147-2.63.el6                       base
usbredir.x86_64                       0.5.1-2.el6                        base
vim-common.x86_64                     2:7.4.629-5.el6                    base
vim-enhanced.x86_64                   2:7.4.629-5.el6                    base
vim-minimal.x86_64                    2:7.4.629-5.el6                    base
virt-manager.x86_64                   0.9.0-29.el6                       base
wireless-tools.x86_64                 1:29-6.el6                         base
xorg-x11-drv-ati-firmware.noarch      7.5.99-3.el6                       base
yum.noarch                            3.2.29-69.el6.centos               base
yum-cron.noarch                       3.2.29-69.el6.centos               base
Obsoleting Packages
yum.noarch                            3.2.29-69.el6.centos               base
    yum-plugin-downloadonly.noarch    1.1.30-30.el6                      @base
Error: Package: php56u-pecl-imagick-3.1.2-5.ius.centos6.x86_64 (@ius)
           Requires: libMagickWand.so.2()(64bit)
           Removing: ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-7.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
               libMagickWand.so.2()(64bit)
           Updated By: ImageMagick-6.7.2.7-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
Error: Package: php56u-pecl-imagick-3.1.2-5.ius.centos6.x86_64 (@ius)
           Requires: libMagickCore.so.2()(64bit)
           Removing: ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-7.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
               libMagickCore.so.2()(64bit)
           Updated By: ImageMagick-6.7.2.7-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Updates downloaded, use "yum -C update" manually to install them.
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As you can see from the output, the release version has changed from 6.6 to 6.7:

```
centos-release.x86_64                 6-7.el6.centos.12.3                base
```

So this is perfectly normal.

http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.7

Comment: I had just twigged moments before you posted, but the answer is correct and will be useful for someone else I'm sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The key thing to pick up is `centos-release.x86_64`, which is being upgraded to `6-7.el6.centos.12.3`.  You haven't said which subversion of CentOS you're on, but assuming you're up to patch, you're on 6.6 - this is the new 6.7 release hitting the mirrors.

Those of us using the `cr` (continuous release) repository saw many of these packages arrive late last week.

Answer (score 2):

> Or has something gone wrong in my system?
>
> ```
> Error: Package: php56u-pecl-imagick-3.1.2-5.ius.centos6.x86_64 (@ius)
>            Requires: libMagickWand.so.2()(64bit)
>            Removing: ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-7.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
>                libMagickWand.so.2()(64bit)
>            Updated By: ImageMagick-6.7.2.7-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                Not found
> Error: Package: php56u-pecl-imagick-3.1.2-5.ius.centos6.x86_64 (@ius)
>            Requires: libMagickCore.so.2()(64bit)
>            Removing: ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-7.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
>                libMagickCore.so.2()(64bit)
>            Updated By: ImageMagick-6.7.2.7-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                Not found
>  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
> Updates downloaded, use "yum -C update" manually to install them.
> ```

The error you are seeing is due to the fact that php56u-pecl-imagick is compiled against ImageMagick, which had a major update in RHEL/CentOS 6.7. The problem was quickly corrected by IUS. More details can be found here:

https://lists.launchpad.net/ius-community/msg01566.html